# Serializing Multipart Form requests for testing on Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I'm working on play2.1 writing a test for a post controller that uses multipart forms using the route function.

```
route(
  FakeRequest(POST,
    postControllerRoute().url,
    FakeHeaders(Seq(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE -> Seq("multipart/form-data"))),
    body = body
  ).withAuthToken.withAdmin(adminId))
```

I've found that for this code to work I need to define a writeable of this type Writeable[MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]] since my body variable is of type MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]. I'm not sure how to serialize a multipart request or if this is even the right approach. Any suggestions?

*Edited*

Answer: Skip the router and use the controller directly like in the docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFunctionalTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have two options, searializing `MultiPartFormData` which is (as far as I can tell) quite tricky to do. This post might help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/MPtQlX-cWMQ
- You can skip going though the `route` method. If you want to test the `Action` in your controller, you can simply bypass the route. See [Testing your Controllers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFunctionalTest) in the documentation. If you do not go through the router, you don't need to supply a `Writable`. It is rarely needed to go through the router which essentially let's you first write it as bytes (using `Writer`) and then (using the body parser) convert it back to something Play understands.

Comment: Well, yes but I want to test multi part form. My controller uses the body parser for MultipartFormData

Comment: I am sorry, yesterday my mind read `FormUrlEncoded` as `MultipartFormData`.

Comment: should have been obvious...I don't need to test the router to test the controller. Thanks for your nudge in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to skip route, you need a Writeable[AnyContentAsMultipartFormData], which turns MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] into Array[Byte].

There's a Writeable[AnyContentAsMultipartFormData] here: http://tech.fongmun.com/post/125479939452/test-multipartformdata-in-play